# Iterating object variable names in C++

Tags: c++, gtk2

I have a GUI written using GTK+ 2.0 and a dialog that has 8 tabs for different pages. On each page I have a five GTK::Entry fields for text input. This totals to 40 variables that I need to write a callback function for when the "Enter" key is pressed.

What I want to know is if it is possible to iterate and change the variable names according to which number tab I'm on. For example:

name_entry0

place_entry0

type_entry0

**THEN**

name_entry1

place_entry1

type_entry1

etc...

Basically creating a variable with its associated tab number on the end of the variable, using a for loop so I don't have to do it 8 times for each variable.

Comment: Sounds like you need an array where the index is the tab number.

Comment: So I would need 8 arrays then with each entry associated in the tab?

Comment: Either that or you define a `Tab` struct that holds each element for the tab and then you just have a single array of `Tab`'s.